# How To Fix A Vector Changing The Variables Of All The Objects?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, vector, directx

I've Created An Image Class That Loads A Bitmap And Then Draws and Handles The Bitmap, But When I Create A Vector Of This Image Class And Load The Bitmap Of 3 Objects **The Last Object (3rd) Sets All Of The Objects To It's Bitmap.**

**Loading Bitmaps:**

```
PlayerCard[0].GetBitmap(L"program files/Creature Cards/Mana_Wyrm.png");
PlayerCard[1].GetBitmap(L"program files/Creature Cards/Snowchugger.png");
PlayerCard[2].GetBitmap(L"program files/Creature Cards/Water_Elemental.png");
```

What Renders In The Window Is 3 Water Elementals.

**GetBitmap(wchar_t* filename): Image Function**

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWICImagingFactory, (LPVOID*)&wicFactory);

wicFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(filename, 0, GENERIC_READ, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &wicDecoder);

wicDecoder->GetFrame(0, &wicFrame);

wicFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&wicConverter);

wicConverter->Initialize(wicFrame, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, 0, 0.0, WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom);

graphics.GetRenderTarget()->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(wicConverter, 0, &bmp);

if (wicFactory) wicFactory->Release();
if (wicDecoder) wicDecoder->Release();
if (wicFrame) wicFrame->Release();
if (wicConverter) wicConverter->Release();
```

**Image Header:Image.h**

```
public:
void PassGraphics(Graphics gfx);
void Init();
void Unload();
void GetBitmap(wchar_t* filename);
void Draw(float x, float y);
private:
IWICImagingFactory *wicFactory;
IWICBitmapDecoder *wicDecoder;
IWICBitmapFrameDecode *wicFrame;
IWICFormatConverter *wicConverter;
ID2D1Bitmap* bmp;
Graphics graphics;
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the code to find out why calling `GetBitmap()` on one instance of `Image` is modifying a previous instance? The code you showed is fairly isolated and should not be suffering from this issue, so it has to be a bug elsewhere in your code. Maybe your rendering code is skipping the first 2 `Image` objects and drawing the last `Image` object in their place. BTW, since `wicFactory`, `wicDecoder`, `wicFrame`, and `wicConverter` are created and released locally in `GetBitmap()`, their declarations belong in there, not in `Image.h` at all.

Comment: [Unless you're a Golem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golems_%28Discworld%29#Communication), please don't capitalize everything.

Comment: Wow I Think I Am A Golem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but the for loop that was used to draw the vector images was the problem.

```
for (float i = 0; i <= 769; i += 384)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
    {
        PlayerCard[c].Draw(i, 100);
    }
}
```

I replaced this for loop to a manual draw call function.

```
PlayerCard[0].Draw(0, 100);
PlayerCard[1].Draw(384, 100);
PlayerCard[2].Draw(769, 100);
```